# HTML button's class not shown in svg on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I've a weird problem with buttons in HTML 5. First of all, here the code:

```
<svg id="MIMIC" width="900" height="600"  viewBox="0 0 900 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- A lot of other things -->
    <foreignObject x="0" y="30" width="160" height="300">
        <input type="button" value="Run" class="cycle_btn_off" name="cycle_run_button" id="cycle_run_button" 
            data-tav-animation-executefunction-expr="[PS_STAT]==1" 
            data-tav-animation-executefunction-param="turnOffCycleButton('cycle_run_button');turnOnCycleButton('cycle_run_button')"
            data-tav-animation-confirmfunction-expr="[C_RUN_SW]" 
            data-tav-animation-confirmfunction-param="true;;<%= lang_config.START_PB_CONFIRM_ON_LONG[ejs_user_lang] %>;startCycle(principal_machine_number)" 
        />
        <input type="button" value="Reset" class="cycle_btn_off" name="cycle_reset_button" id="cycle_reset_button" 
            data-tav-animation-executefunction-expr="[PS_STAT]==3" 
            data-tav-animation-executefunction-param="turnOffCycleButton('cycle_reset_button');turnOnCycleButton('cycle_reset_button')" 
            data-tav-animation-confirmfunction-expr="[C_RST_PB]" 
            data-tav-animation-confirmfunction-param="true;;<%= lang_config.END_PB_CONFIRM_ON_LONG[ejs_user_lang] %>;resetCycle(principal_machine_number)" />
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Some explanation: the attributes *data-tav-animation-etc* are custom attributes that I parse with a script; now put focus on *executefunction*.
There are two attributes, *expr* and *param*. The first is used to evaluate a boolean expression, if it results **true** then execute the function after the semicolon, otherwise execute the function before the semicolon. The value *[PS_STAT]* arrives from a PLC connected via socket with node.js.

The functions *turnOnCycleButton* and *turnOffCycleButton* are simple functions that add and remove a class:

```
function turnOffCycleButton(id){
    changeButtonStyle(id, 'cycle_btn_off', 'cycle_btn_on');
}

function turnOnCycleButton(id){
    changeButtonStyle(id, 'cycle_btn_on', 'cycle_btn_off');
}

function changeButtonStyle(id, addClass, removeClass){
    var btn = $('#'+id);
    btn.addClass(addClass);
    btn.removeClass(removeClass);
}
```

Now the weird thing: on Firefox all works correctly but not on Chrome. Infact on Chrome the value of PS_STAT arrives correctly, the functions are called and classes are managed in the right way but the colors of the buttons don't change EVEN IF THE CSS IS SET CORRECTLY!!! (see the screen)
[image: Weird things happen!]

If I refresh the page or even click on one button the style is refreshed and the buttons have the correct color.

If I move the buttons outside the SVG they works correctly.

Comment: can you show this in fiddle

Comment: Well, no because I can't reproduce all the conditions of the project on fiddle.
I know that the problem is that the buttons are inside the SVG, as I said if I move that outside the SVG all go well

Comment: As i see it, you should force a redraw of UI. Test it: `btn.hide().show(0);` after changing classes. Or maybe apply it to svg element instead: `$('#MIMIC').hide().show(0);`

Comment: Ok, this way works but it's really necessary hide and show the entire svg? Using the same tecnique I'll "refresh" only the button. Is this the only way to refresh an item?

Comment: @MaxMarkson search for it, sometimes e.g just calling (no need to set) any css property is enough but depends how browser handles it: `$('#MIMIC')[0].offsetHeight;`

Comment: Ok I'll try...I thought there was a real "refresh" function. Thanks for help, if you add an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing namspace:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

Comment: Why does this fix the issue?

Comment: Actually, I don't know if it would fix it. But I suspect the incorrect namespace could cause problems betweem browsers.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) could be a normative reference? If it qualifies as such , please add it to your answer.